# Why does line repeat itself in while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, while-loop

I have made a simple program which has the choice of adding, voting, and viewing votes on 3 different candidates. For some reason, the line 18 repeats itself and the line 72 after it, for example, if you begin, press 1 to create a candidate, type in the name and press enter, it will come through as this:

```
Add candidate (1) or vote (2) or view number of votes on each candidate (3): Incorrect number, please try again.
```

but then goes back to normal...

```
Add candidate (1) or vote (2) or view number of votes on each candidate (3):
```

Here is the whole code (repeating lines are noted):

```
package array;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] Vote_Choice = {'A', 'B', 'C'};
        String[] candidates = { "none", "none", "none"};
        int[] votes = {0, 0, 0};


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            boolean done2 = false;
                System.out.print("Add candidate (1) or vote (2) or view number of votes on each candidate (3): ");   // here (line 18)

            switch (input.nextLine()) {
                case "1": System.out.print("Type new candidates name: ");
                    while (!done2) {
                        if (candidates[0].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[0] = input.next();
                        done2 = true;
                    }
                        else if (!candidates[0].equals("none") && candidates[1].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[1] = input.next();
                        done2 = true;

                    }
                    else if (!candidates[0].equals("none") && !candidates[1].equals("none") && candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[2] = input.next();
                        done2 = true;
                    }
                    else if (!candidates[0].equals("none") && !candidates[1].equals("none") && !candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                        System.out.println("Sorry, all candidate slots are full.");
                        done2 = true;
                    }
                    }
                        break;
                case "2":
                    System.out.println("Type letter corresponding to the candidate you wish to vote for: ");

                    System.out.print("Type A for candidate "+ candidates[0] +", type B for candidate "+candidates[1]+", type C for candidate "+candidates[2]+": ");
                    String choice = input.next();
                    if (choice.equals("A")) {
                        votes[0]++;
                    }
                    if (choice.equals("B")) {
                        votes[1]++;
                    }
                    if (choice.equals("C")) {
                        votes[2]++;
                    }


                    break;
                case "3": if (!candidates[0].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate "+ candidates[0] +": "+votes[0]);
                } 
                            if (!candidates[1].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate "+ candidates[1] +": "+votes[1]);
                } 
                            if (!candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate "+ candidates[2] +": "+votes[2]);
                } 
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Sorry, there are no current candidates.");
                            }
                break;
                default: System.out.println("Incorrect number, please try again.");  // And here, line 72
            }       

        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Remember, we cannot see which line is line 18, or which line is line 72.

Comment: i noted beside the lines which are affected, you'll just have to look :)

Comment: Any chance you could indent the code properly too? The case 1 is made particularly difficult to read because the closing brace which looks like it belongs to the while loop, actually belongs to the if. It may seem pedantic, but if your code it difficult to read, people won't want to read it :). If you are using eclipse, press Ctrl + Shift + F all at the same time, or Command-Shift-F on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have `input.next()` instead of `input.nextLine()` there. The end of line "stays" in input stream and when you call it, it returns what left in that stream (often the empty string).

Answer (score 0):

When you call:

```
candidates[1] = input.next();
```

This is causing the problem, as it only consumes part of the input.

If you consider the input stream from the keyboard may be something like:
1\nDavid\n

What is happening is you are reading "1\n" when you read the line, then when you read "next" you read "David", but not the new line characters, so next time you call nextLine you get the empty line, starting with \n (\n is a new line character).

Your code should be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Array {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] Vote_Choice = { 'A', 'B', 'C' };
        String[] candidates = { "none", "none", "none" };
        int[] votes = { 0, 0, 0 };

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
            boolean done2 = false;
            System.out
                    .print("Add candidate (1) or vote (2) or view number of votes on each candidate (3): "); // here
                                                                                                                // (line
                                                                                                                // 18)

            switch (input.nextLine()) {
            case "1":
                System.out.print("Type new candidates name: ");
                while (!done2) {
                    if (candidates[0].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[0] = input.nextLine();
                        done2 = true;
                    } else if (!candidates[0].equals("none")
                            && candidates[1].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[1] = input.nextLine();
                        done2 = true;

                    } else if (!candidates[0].equals("none")
                            && !candidates[1].equals("none")
                            && candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                        candidates[2] = input.nextLine();
                        done2 = true;
                    } else if (!candidates[0].equals("none")
                            && !candidates[1].equals("none")
                            && !candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                        System.out
                                .println("Sorry, all candidate slots are full.");
                        done2 = true;
                    }
                }
                break;
            case "2":
                System.out
                        .println("Type letter corresponding to the candidate you wish to vote for: ");

                System.out.print("Type A for candidate " + candidates[0]
                        + ", type B for candidate " + candidates[1]
                        + ", type C for candidate " + candidates[2] + ": ");
                String choice = input.nextLine();
                if (choice.equals("A")) {
                    votes[0]++;
                }
                if (choice.equals("B")) {
                    votes[1]++;
                }
                if (choice.equals("C")) {
                    votes[2]++;
                }

                break;
            case "3":
                if (!candidates[0].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate " + candidates[0] + ": "
                            + votes[0]);
                }
                if (!candidates[1].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate " + candidates[1] + ": "
                            + votes[1]);
                }
                if (!candidates[2].equals("none")) {
                    System.out.println("Candidate " + candidates[2] + ": "
                            + votes[2]);
                } else {
                    System.out
                            .println("Sorry, there are no current candidates.");
                }
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect number, please try again."); // And
                                                                            // here,
                                                                            // line
                                                                            // 72
            }

        }

    }
}
```